# How to check if images are loaded?

Tags: jquery, mjpeg

I am using [mjpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) format to display stream from IP-camera. The problems is that stream is unstable and i don't know when exactly it starts and so i need somehow check image url if there is for example > 5 images and then load it. Something like this, but check **url** before adding it to the page.

At the moment i have:

```
$('#image_div').append('<img width="320" height="240" border="0" src="http://'+url+':'+port+'/?up" id="image">');
$('#image').load(function(){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

In console it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM88J.png

If there is no stream i receiving only one of this. So i need somehow check it before adding.

Comment: How do you mean "check image url if there are > 5 images". Do you want to read a remote HTML page and count IMG tags?

Comment: @David http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG

Comment: So you mean "check **stream** URL"? Can you post some more markup/code?

Comment: @David just updated post

Answer (score 1):

This is a great plugin that i've used in the past. For the most part it worked smoothly across most browsers.

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what this does:

```
$('#image_div').append('<img src="http://'+url+':'+port+'/?up">');
```

I have never worked with mjpeg and javascript, but I assume this URL is a stream of jpegs.

Anyway, you can create image objects, load them into memory and display them whenever you want. F.ex:

```
var cache = [];
$(new Image()).attr('src', 'http://'+url+':'+port+'/?up').load(function() {
    // image loaded but not injected
    cache.push(this);
    if ( cache.length == 5 ) {
        // 5 images loaded, do something with cache array
    }
});
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: If there loaded 5 images i need just return true and stop function. Can you help me with these if it is not difficult for youю

Comment: I’m not sure, but try `$(this).unbind('load');`